# Sharepoint online 2013, Move term to another branch (parent)

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

In Sharepoint online we can move Term manually. I need that to be done programatically using JSOM. Does anyone have code for that?

I checked 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269588.aspx
and but does not have such a method.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [SP.Taxonomy.Term.move Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312574.aspx) to move the *current* [Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) object to be a *child* of a different Term.

**Example**

```
function moveTerm(sourceTermId,targetTermId,success,error)
{
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var ts = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
    var termStore = ts.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    var sourceTerm = termStore.getTerm(sourceTermId);
    var targetTerm = termStore.getTerm(targetTermId);
    sourceTerm.move(targetTerm);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
}
```

**Usage**

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession'], function(){

   var sourceTermId = 'source-term-guid';
   var targetTermId = 'target-term-guid';

   moveTerm(sourceTermId,targetTermId,
     function(){
        console.log(String.format('Term {0} has been moved under Term {0}',sourceTermId,targetTermId));
     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works, Its not easy to find resources or sample for sharepoint 2013, JSOM. thanks again –

Comment: Hi This works fine. I tried this code to move Term2 to under Term1, and it works perfectly. But when i try to use this code to move subterm2 under 1st level of structure it doesn't work.. Any idea? 
Term1=> subterm1, subterm2
Term2

Comment: This code is working perfectly, @vadim, If there is sub term 1( Under My Term 1), how can we move that to My Term Set ? i tried that by giving My term Set GUID, but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: I figure out the solution for above question, i pointed through a comment. var targetTerm = termStore.getTerm(targetTermId); should be changed to the getTermSet
Thanks